# apt-get autoremove texlive removed a whole lot of unrelated stuff!

Tags: apt, package-management, texlive

I just ran apt-get autoremove texlive, and this is what it removed!

What happened?  Why would it do this?  Is there some easy way to automatically reinstall all of these packages?

```
Removing account-plugin-aim (3.8.6-0ubuntu9.2) ...
Removing account-plugin-google (0.11+14.04.20140409.1-0ubuntu2) ...
Removing account-plugin-jabber (3.8.6-0ubuntu9.2) ...
Removing account-plugin-salut (3.8.6-0ubuntu9.2) ...
Removing account-plugin-yahoo (3.8.6-0ubuntu9.2) ...
Removing argyll (1.5.1-5ubuntu1) ...
Removing gnome-core (1:3.8+4ubuntu3) ...
Removing baobab (3.8.2-1ubuntu1) ...
Removing browser-plugin-gnash (0.8.11~git20130903-3ubuntu1) ...
Removing caribou-antler (0.4.13-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing caribou (0.4.13-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing cheese (3.10.2-0ubuntu2) ...
Removing dconf-tools (0.20.0-1) ...
Removing dconf-editor (0.20.0-1) ...
Removing nautilus-sendto-empathy (3.8.6-0ubuntu9.2) ...
Removing mcp-account-manager-uoa (3.8.6-0ubuntu9.2) ...
Removing empathy (3.8.6-0ubuntu9.2) ...
Removing empathy-common (3.8.6-0ubuntu9.2) ...
Removing file-roller (3.10.2.1-0ubuntu4.1) ...
Removing gnome-contacts (3.8.3-1ubuntu1) ...
Removing libfolks-telepathy25:amd64 (0.9.5-1ubuntu5) ...
Removing libfolks-eds25:amd64 (0.9.5-1ubuntu5) ...
Removing libfolks25:amd64 (0.9.5-1ubuntu5) ...
Removing folks-common (0.9.5-1ubuntu5) ...
Removing fonts-cantarell (0.0.15-1) ...
Removing gdebi (0.9.5.3ubuntu2) ...
Removing gdebi-core (0.9.5.3ubuntu2) ...
Removing gdm (3.10.0.1-0ubuntu3.1) ...
Removing gedit-plugins (3.10.1-1ubuntu2) ...
Removing gedit (3.10.4-0ubuntu4) ...
Removing gedit-common (3.10.4-0ubuntu4) ...
Removing gnome-shell-extensions (3.10.1-0ubuntu2) ...
Removing gnome-shell (3.10.4-0ubuntu5.2) ...
Removing gir1.2-accountsservice-1.0 (0.6.35-0ubuntu7.2) ...
Removing python-pyatspi (2.10.0+dfsg-1) ...
Removing gnome-orca (3.10.3-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing python3-pyatspi (2.10.0+dfsg-1) ...
Removing gir1.2-atspi-2.0 (2.10.2.is.2.10.1-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing gir1.2-caribou-1.0 (0.4.13-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing gir1.2-gcr-3 (3.10.1-1) ...
Removing gir1.2-gck-1 (3.10.1-1) ...
Removing gnome-documents (3.10.2-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing gir1.2-gdata-0.0 (0.14.1-1) ...
Removing gir1.2-gdm-1.0 (3.10.0.1-0ubuntu3.1) ...
Removing gir1.2-gkbd-3.0 (3.6.0-0ubuntu2) ...
Removing rhythmbox-plugins (3.0.2-0ubuntu2) ...
Removing gir1.2-gnomekeyring-1.0 (3.8.0-2) ...
Removing gir1.2-goa-1.0 (3.10.3-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing gir1.2-gtop-2.0 (2.28.5-2) ...
Removing gir1.2-gucharmap-2.90 (1:3.10.1-0ubuntu2) ...
Removing gir1.2-mutter-3.0 (3.10.4-0ubuntu2.1) ...
Removing gir1.2-nmgtk-1.0 (0.9.8.8-0ubuntu4.3) ...
Removing gir1.2-networkmanager-1.0 (0.9.8.8-0ubuntu7.1) ...
Removing gir1.2-polkit-1.0 (0.105-4ubuntu2.14.04.1) ...
Removing rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist (3.0.2-0ubuntu2) ...
Removing rhythmbox-mozilla (3.0.2-0ubuntu2) ...
Removing gir1.2-zpj-0.0 (0.0.3-1ubuntu1) ...
Removing gir1.2-rest-0.7 (0.7.90-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing gir1.2-telepathylogger-0.2 (0.8.0-3) ...
Removing gir1.2-telepathyglib-0.12 (0.22.1-1ubuntu2) ...
Removing gir1.2-tracker-0.16 (0.16.5-0ubuntu0.1) ...
Removing gir1.2-upowerglib-1.0 (0.9.23-2ubuntu1) ...
Removing gir1.2-wnck-3.0 (3.4.7-0ubuntu3.1) ...
Removing gir1.2-xkl-1.0 (5.4-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing gir1.2-zeitgeist-2.0 (0.9.14-0ubuntu4.1) ...
Removing gjs (1.40.1-0ubuntu0.3) ...
Removing gksu (2.0.2-6ubuntu2) ...
Removing gnash (0.8.11~git20130903-3ubuntu1) ...
Removing gnash-common (0.8.11~git20130903-3ubuntu1) ...
Removing gnome-backgrounds (3.12.0-1) ...
Removing gnome-calculator (1:3.10.3-0ubuntu0.1.1) ...
Removing gnome-color-manager (3.8.3-1ubuntu1) ...
Removing gnome-dictionary (3.10.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Removing gnome-disk-utility (3.10.0-1ubuntu3) ...
Removing gnome-font-viewer (3.8.0-1build1) ...
Removing gnome-icon-theme-extras (3.12.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Removing gnome-nettool (3.8.1-1) ...
Removing gnome-online-accounts (3.10.3-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing gnome-online-miners (3.10.3-0ubuntu3) ...
Removing gnome-packagekit (3.8.2-4ubuntu1) ...
Removing gnome-packagekit-session (3.8.2-4ubuntu1) ...
Removing gnome-packagekit-data (3.8.2-4ubuntu1) ...
Removing gnome-screenshot (3.10.1-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing gnome-tweak-tool (3.10.1-2ubuntu1) ...
Removing gnome-shell-common (3.10.4-0ubuntu5.2) ...
Removing gnome-system-log (3.8.1-1svn1) ...
Removing gnome-video-effects (0.4.1-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing grilo-plugins-0.2:amd64 (0.2.12-2) ...
Removing gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad:amd64 (0.10.23-7.2ubuntu1.1) ...
Removing libtelepathy-farstream3:amd64 (0.6.1-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libfarstream-0.2-2:amd64 (0.2.3-1ubuntu2) ...
Removing gstreamer1.0-nice:amd64 (0.1.4-1) ...
Removing gtk2-engines:amd64 (1:2.20.2-3ubuntu1) ...
Removing gucharmap (1:3.10.1-0ubuntu2) ...
Removing hamster-indicator (0.1+037dd2e-0ubuntu2) ...
Removing hamster-applet (2.91.3+git20120514.b9fec3e1-1ubuntu1) ...
Removing libaacs0:amd64 (0.7.1-1~trusty) ...
Removing libasound2:i386 (1.0.27.2-3ubuntu7) ...
Removing libatk-adaptor:amd64 (2.10.2-2ubuntu1) ...
Removing vinagre (3.10.2-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libavahi-ui-gtk3-0:amd64 (0.6.31-4ubuntu1) ...
Removing libbluray1:amd64 (1:0.6.2-1~trusty) ...
Removing python-gnome2 (2.28.1+dfsg-1ubuntu2) ...
Removing libgnomeui-0:amd64 (2.24.5-3) ...
Removing libbonoboui2-0:amd64 (2.24.5-0ubuntu3) ...
Removing libbonoboui2-common (2.24.5-0ubuntu3) ...
Removing libcaribou0:amd64 (0.4.13-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libcaribou-common (0.4.13-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libcaribou-gtk-module:amd64 (0.4.13-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libcaribou-gtk3-module:amd64 (0.4.13-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libcdaudio1 (0.99.12p2-13) ...
Removing libcolord-gtk1:amd64 (0.1.25-1.1) ...
Removing libdirac-encoder0:amd64 (1.0.2-6ubuntu1) ...
Removing libdirectfb-1.2-9:amd64 (1.2.10.0-5) ...
Removing sound-juicer (3.5.0-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libdiscid0:amd64 (0.6.1-2) ...
Removing libdmapsharing-3.0-2 (2.9.24-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing transmission-gtk (2.82-1.1ubuntu3.1) ...
Removing libevent-2.0-5:amd64 (2.0.21-stable-1ubuntu1.14.04.1) ...
Removing libfontconfig1:i386 (2.11.0-0ubuntu4.1) ...
Removing libexpat1:i386 (2.1.0-4ubuntu1.1) ...
Removing libfreetype6:i386 (2.5.2-1ubuntu2.4) ...
Removing libgail-common:amd64 (2.24.23-0ubuntu1.2) ...
Removing libgnomecanvas2-0:amd64 (2.30.3-2) ...
Removing libgail18:amd64 (2.24.23-0ubuntu1.2) ...
Removing libgdict-1.0-6 (3.10.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Removing libgdict-common (3.10.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Removing libgdm1 (3.10.0.1-0ubuntu3.1) ...
Removing shotwell (0.18.0-0ubuntu4.3) ...
Removing rygel-preferences (0.20.3-1ubuntu2) ...
Removing libgexiv2-2:amd64 (0.10.0-1ubuntu2) ...
Removing libgksu2-0 (2.0.13~pre1-6ubuntu4) ...
Removing libgnomecanvas2-common (2.30.3-2) ...
Removing libgnomeui-common (2.24.5-3) ...
Removing libgrilo-0.2-1:amd64 (0.2.10-1) ...
Removing tracker-miner-fs (0.16.5-0ubuntu0.1) ...
Removing tracker-extract (0.16.5-0ubuntu0.1) ...
Removing libgsf-1-114 (1.14.27-2ubuntu2) ...
Removing libgsf-1-common (1.14.27-2ubuntu2) ...
Removing libgstreamer-plugins-bad0.10-0:amd64 (0.10.23-7.2ubuntu1.1) ...
Removing libgtk-vnc-2.0-0 (0.5.3-0ubuntu2) ...
Removing rygel-playbin (0.20.3-1ubuntu2) ...
Removing rygel (0.20.3-1ubuntu2) ...
Removing librygel-server-2.0-1 (0.20.3-1ubuntu2) ...
Removing libgupnp-dlna-2.0-3 (0.10.2-1ubuntu1) ...
Removing libgvnc-1.0-0 (0.5.3-0ubuntu2) ...
Removing libicc2:amd64 (2.12+argyll1.5.1-5ubuntu1) ...
Removing libsm6:i386 (2:1.2.1-2) ...
Removing libice6:i386 (2:1.0.8-2) ...
Removing libimdi0:amd64 (1.5.1-5ubuntu1) ...
Removing libtracker-extract-0.16-0 (0.16.5-0ubuntu0.1) ...
Removing libiptcdata0 (1.0.4-3ubuntu3) ...
Removing libjemalloc1 (3.5.1-2) ...
Removing libjpeg62:i386 (6b1-4ubuntu1) ...
Removing liblinear-tools (1.8+dfsg-1ubuntu1) ...
Removing nmap (6.40-0.2ubuntu1) ...
Removing liblinear1 (1.8+dfsg-1ubuntu1) ...
Removing python3-louis (2.5.3-2ubuntu1) ...
Removing liblouis2:amd64 (2.5.3-2ubuntu1) ...
Removing liblouis-data (2.5.3-2ubuntu1) ...
Removing liblua5.2-0:amd64 (5.2.3-1) ...
Removing libmediaart-1.0-0:amd64 (0.4.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Removing vino (3.8.1-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing libminiupnpc8 (1.6-3ubuntu2.14.04.1) ...
Removing libmkv0:amd64 (0.6.5.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Removing libmutter0c (3.10.4-0ubuntu2.1) ...
Removing libnatpmp1 (20110808-3ubuntu2) ...
Removing libreoffice-gnome (1:4.2.8-0ubuntu2) ...
Removing libreoffice-gtk (1:4.2.8-0ubuntu2) ...
Removing rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder (3.0.2-0ubuntu2) ...
Removing librygel-renderer-gst-2.0-1 (0.20.3-1ubuntu2) ...
Removing librygel-renderer-2.0-1 (0.20.3-1ubuntu2) ...
Removing librygel-core-2.0-1 (0.20.3-1ubuntu2) ...
Removing libslv2-9 (0.6.6+dfsg1-2) ...
Removing tracker-utils (0.16.5-0ubuntu0.1) ...
Removing tracker-gui (0.16.5-0ubuntu0.1) ...
Removing tracker (0.16.5-0ubuntu0.1) ...
Removing libtracker-miner-0.16-0 (0.16.5-0ubuntu0.1) ...
Removing libtracker-sparql-0.16-0 (0.16.5-0ubuntu0.1) ...
Removing libts-0.0-0:amd64 (1.0-12) ...
Removing python-wnck (2.32.0+dfsg-3) ...
Removing libwnck22 (1:2.30.7-0ubuntu4) ...
Removing libwnck-common (1:2.30.7-0ubuntu4) ...
Removing libxrandr2:i386 (2:1.4.2-1) ...
Removing libxrender1:i386 (1:0.9.8-1build0.14.04.1) ...
Removing libxfixes3:i386 (1:5.0.1-1ubuntu1.1) ...
Removing libxdamage1:i386 (1:1.1.4-1ubuntu1) ...
Removing libxtst6:i386 (2:1.2.2-1) ...
Removing libxinerama1:i386 (2:1.1.3-1) ...
Removing libxext6:i386 (2:1.3.2-1ubuntu0.0.14.04.1) ...
Removing libzapojit-0.0-0 (0.0.3-1ubuntu1) ...
Removing libzvbi0:amd64 (0.2.35-2) ...
Removing libzvbi-common (0.2.35-2) ...
Removing mutter-common (3.10.4-0ubuntu2.1) ...
Removing nautilus-sendto (3.6.1-2ubuntu1) ...
Removing python-appindicator (12.10.1+13.10.20130920-0ubuntu4.1) ...
Removing python-pyorbit (2.24.0-6ubuntu4) ...
Removing python3-brlapi (5.0-2ubuntu2) ...
Removing python3-mako (0.9.1-1) ...
Removing python3-markupsafe (0.18-1build2) ...
Removing python3-speechd (0.8-5ubuntu1) ...
Removing seahorse (3.10.2-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing sensible-mda (8.14.4-4.1ubuntu1) ...
Removing shotwell-common (0.18.0-0ubuntu4.3) ...
Removing signon-plugin-password (8.56+14.04.20140307-0ubuntu2) ...
Removing simple-scan (3.12.1-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing transmission-common (2.82-1.1ubuntu3.1) ...
Removing tsconf (1.0-12) ...
Removing unity-asset-pool (0.8.24daily13.06.10-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing unoconv (0.6-6) ...
Removing xdg-user-dirs-gtk (0.10-1ubuntu1) ...
Removing rhythmbox (3.0.2-0ubuntu2) ...
Removing gir1.2-rb-3.0 (3.0.2-0ubuntu2) ...
Removing libgee-0.8-2:amd64 (0.10.5-1ubuntu1) ...
Removing libgupnp-av-1.0-2 (0.12.5-1ubuntu1) ...
Removing librhythmbox-core8 (3.0.2-0ubuntu2) ...
Removing libx11-6:i386 (2:1.6.2-1ubuntu2) ...
Removing libxcb1:i386 (1.10-2ubuntu1) ...
Removing libxau6:i386 (1:1.0.8-1) ...
Removing libxdmcp6:i386 (1:1.1.1-1) ...
Removing rhythmbox-data (3.0.2-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.6) ...
Processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:amd64 (2.40.2-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.54ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.13-1) ...
Processing triggers for gconf2 (3.2.6-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for fontconfig (2.11.0-0ubuntu4.1) ...
Processing triggers for install-info (5.2.0.dfsg.1-2) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.2-0ubuntu3) ...
```

Comment: Did you remove `ubuntu-gnome-desktop` previously?

Comment: This is the exact command.  'sudo apt-get autoremove texlive'.  And I think texlive is a package.  When I apt-get install it, it says this, '...texlive is already the newest version...'  I have Kubuntu, but I use gnome desktop.

Comment: Ah, ok, you are right. Strange. I tried in simulation mode and  `texlive` remove just tex related packages here. Did you remove (with `remove`, not `autoremove`) some other package before?

Answer (score 0):

You say, you use GNOME desktop. But you have removed your GNOME desktop. Why? I have no idea. Reinstall the desktop via

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-gnome-desktop gdm
```

After that, read the list of removed packages and install the packages again which you need, e.g. `gnome-shell-extensions`, `sound-juicer` and so on.

Comment: autoremove has removed Gnome Desktop even though I have manually installed Gnome Desktop.  I am asking why this happened.